# Unwanted image title in the business page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

In the [Stack Overflow Business](https://business.stackoverflow.com/?ref=topbar_help) page, the below two images having unwanted image title as `home1.png`, `home2.png`. Hope those are need to be remove.

I'm not sure post about stack overflow business is valid here. If it is not the right place, feel free to remove.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Image 1]
>
> ---
>
> [image: Image 2]

Comment: Sure enough, the `title="home1.png"` is bad web design. It does not *add* information, it just repeats it.

Comment: @RadLexus This has to be an accident. StackOverflow, a company whose roots are in programming nerds, would never allow a page on any of their websites to contain such an amateurish mistake.

Comment: @DavidB: any possibiliy Jon Skeet's rep broke it?

Comment: @RadLexus Yes, there is a possibility.

Comment: @DavidB: Nobody's perfect. Just because you're a "programming nerd" doesn't mean you are beyond reproach. As with any large system, there have been plenty of questionable design and implementation decisions here over the years. We report them and they get fixed. As it should be. I don't think you can use _appeal to authority_ to question the very possibility of such things occurring!

Comment: I was not suggesting that anybody is infallible. I was merely saying that they would not do this on purpose.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit For example, look at the government!

Comment: I know this is meta and not regular SO, but once the problem is fixed it'd be nice to read about what it was all about. My guess is something along the lines of the trigger BEFORE INSERT on that fills in some fields, when no data is provided, and `title` gets filled with `name` when there is `image_name` would be more appropriate. Or maybe some library that is suppose to get the title from EXIF, but everybody forgot that it defaults to returning the filename.

Comment: This is a comment.  This is the second sentence of a comment.  This is the last sentence of a comment.txt

Comment: These are title attributes within the img tags, and will only appear when hovering over the image. They are sometimes meant as a description of the image for vision impaired users.

Comment: @Yakk I am enlightened!

Comment: With reference to this [meta SE post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279899/topbar-help-link-to-so-business-uses-https-pictures-are-missing), the title issue is fixed. Currently the `title` is coming as [*Stack Overflow Business*](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1VlKJ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With reference to this [meta SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279899/312043), the title issue is fixed.

Currently the title is coming as **Stack Overflow Business** instead of the `home1.png` and `home2.png` :

> [image: Stack Overflow Business title corrected.]

Comment: You should accept your own answer so the system can stop bumping this question.

Comment: @CodyGray an upvote also stops it from bumping, IIRC.